# ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Mar 30 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016" (at offset 4)

Tags: android, string-parsing, android-time-square

Im trying parse a String with a date to convert it into a Date format. Strings are in the following format.

Wed Mar 30 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016

But when im parsing the String i get a error saying,

java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Wed Mar 30 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016" (at offset 4)

below is a part of my code. How do i avoid this error? Any help would be appreciated.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MM dd kk:mm:ss zzzz yyyy",Locale.ENGLISH);

for(int i=0 ; i <jArr.length() ; i++){
    String tempDate = jArr.get(i).toString();
    dateList.add(tempDate);
}

try{
    Date d1 = sdf3.parse(dateList.get(0));                        

}catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
```

Comment: [As you can see your format doesn't fit the data that you wana parse](http://ideone.com/WSfYZ9) `MM`, `zzzz` ? please read the documentation

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` and either `OffsetDateTime` or `ZonedDateTime`; all three are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). See the answer by Arvind Kumar Avinash.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Check this once. 
working fine for me

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

    Date d1 = null;
    try{
        d1 = sdf3.parse("Wed Mar 30 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016");

    }catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }


    System.out.println("check..." + d1);
```

Answer (score 1):

### *java.time*

The `java.util` date-time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> .

**Using modern date-time API:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strDateTime = "Wed Mar 30 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016";
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("E MMM d H:m:s O u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(strDateTime, dtf);
        System.out.println(odt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2016-03-30T00:00+05:30
```

Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

> Wed Mar 30 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2016
>   EEE MM  dd kk:mm:ss zzzz yyyy

Your data doesn't match your pattern. To get it working, update your pattern to

```
"EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss zXXX yyyy"
```

PS: [here](http://www.sdfonlinetester.info/) is a handy tool to test your patterns.

Comment: thanks for the help. i had to use HH instead of kk. thanks for the tool as well. really appreciate it.